# JApplet writing to text file, destroy() / stop()

Tags: java, applet, destroy, printwriter

I am attempting to write a JApplet that uses information in a text file to load and save data from. I have successfully got the applet to load the information, but the saving appears to be having issues. I have included the code to save below. the file name I am using is the same as I use to write to. The file must be included in the JAR when I run because the applet initializes properly. Is there any reason why the writing sin't working properly? i have resorted to calling this method from both the stop() and destroy() methods.

As a note, the load and saving both work perfectly when run from eclipse, but when in a JAR only the loading works, but nothing saves so I can't change the load data.

Ideally, I want this saveLocations() method to be called whenever the page is closed or refreshed.

NOTE: mOUtputStream is indeed a PrintWriter (it used to be an OutputStream, I guess I should change the name)

Thanks so much in advance for the help.

```
private void saveLocations() throws IOException {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alert", "Saving", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        // System.out.println("saving!");
        try {
            mOutputStream = new PrintWriter(new File(getClass().getResource("/listings/saveData.txt").toURI()));
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(locations.size());
        for (Location l : locations) {
            System.out.println("r: " + l.getRawListing());
            mOutputStream.print(l.getRawListing()+ "\n");
        }


        if (mOutputStream != null)
            mOutputStream.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to a file inside a JAR file -- period. Don't even try. If you need to write to a file, then that file has to be outside the JAR. For an applet, that would require it to be signed, and to ask the user for specific permission to do so.

In the applet case, I'm not sure what copy of the JAR file you're hoping will be written to: the copy in the browser cache, or the copy on the server? Either way, it's not going to happen.

Comment: Damn, alright. Thanks. And it was the server copy i was hoping to write to. Is there any other way to allow a user to add data and save it on the server in any form?

Comment: Absolutely! You need some server-side code (in Java, this typically means a Servlet) which receives data from the applet via HTTP, and stores it someplace -- typically in a database. All of this code is pretty simple, and examples abound on the Internet.